# Angular 2 - Child route

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

Got a problem with angular 2 routing, i try lots of things but i still have error message.
I got this url : /project/:projectId . Project page got router-outlet and can have access to this two urls:
/project/:projectId/setting
/project/:projectId/add-card

So my problem is that when my url is on `/project/:projectId/add-card`. I try to access to my setting page with `this.router.navigate(['./', 'setting']);`
and i still have :

> Cannot match any routes: 'setting'(…)

I really don't understand how access to this from code.

This is my parents routes :

```ts
const PROJECT_ROUTES = [
    { 
        path: ':id', 
        CanActivate: [AuthGuard], 
        component: ProjectDetailComponent ,
        loadChildren: './../menu/menu.module#MenuModule',
        resolve: {
            project: ProjectResolver
        }
    },
    { 
        path: '', 
        CanActivate: [AuthGuard], 
        component: ProjectContainerComponent, 
        pathMatch: 'full' 
    }
]
```

This is my child routes :

```ts
const MENU_ROUTES = [
    { path: 'setting', component: MenuSettingComponent },
    { path: 'add-card', component: MenuAddCardComponent},
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'setting' },
];
```

and my code form switch to setting page :

```ts
onOpenMenu() {
    console.log('navigate to setting');
    this.router.navigate(['./', 'setting']);
    this.menuService.menuEvent.emit(true);
}
```

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add another `.` otherwise you're navigating to `/project/:projectId/add-card/setting`

For relative navigation also the current route needs to be passed.

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute){}
```

```
this.router.navigate(['../', 'setting'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```